# How to get all users in one organization unit using Google Directory API

Tags: api, google-apps, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

In the new released Google Directory API,  I cannot find a method to get all users in a specific organization unit of Google Apps.  Is it possible? And how?   Based on the Google Directory API document, programmers can get all the organization  units, or all the users for the whole domain, but there is no description on how to get users of one organization unit.  This feature is crucial important to construct the organizations/users hierarchical tree.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the list of users under a single OU (and only those users). However, you can just grab the full list of users in the Google Apps instance along with their OU using a call to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&fields=nextPageToken%2Cusers(orgUnitPath%2CprimaryEmail)
```

based on [Vic Fryzel's presentation](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/327878419) at I/O, I believe Google plans to continue to improve the capabilities of the query parameter, eventually allowing a query based on OU (as well as other query parameters).

Comment: I cannot make the Directory api work using 2-legged oauth. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try authenticating using the guide at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer. The need for user input is one-time only (to obtain the authorization code) and requires a Google Apps user with access to the user list to work.

Comment: You need to enable the Admin SDK for the API project, before Google Directory API is accessible as well.

Answer (score 1):

After some back and forth with the google dev relations team I was able to get it to work bay adding a query parameter orgUnitPath=/SOMEPATH to the list users call.
Here is an example using the google api php client that's using the directory API:
$users = $directory->users->listUsers(array("domain"=>"example.com","query"=>"orgUnitPath=/SOMEPATH"));

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
UsersResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.List(); 
request.Customer = "my_customer";
request.Query = "orgUnitPath=" + "'" + "/testOu/under testOu/testOu1" + "'";
```